# How to disable inline labels in django inline admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-ckeditor

In my Django admin, I want to disable the below-shown paragraph. Please help me out. I am new to changing djano admin.
[image]
[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xVqk.png)

Here is my current admin.py

```
class ImageInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Image
    max_num = 1

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ParagraphInlineAdmin, ImageInlineAdmin]
    list_display = ['heading','id']
```

Here are my models

```
class Container(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.heading

class Paragraph(models.Model):
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    container = models.ForeignKey(
        Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.content
```

P.S I am using Django CKeditor

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the **str** function from the model that will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I removed it via css trick as follow:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
    
    inlines = [MyTabularAdmin]

    class Media:
        css = {
            'custom': ('css/custom_admin.css',),
        }
```

the css is:

```
.tabular table tbody .original p {
    visibility: hidden;
 }

.inline-group .tabular tr.has_original td {
    padding-top: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override CSS try this:

Instead of:

```py
def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.content
```

Try:

```py
def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `str` function of making it return an empty string does remove the label, but it does not remove the space occupied by the label. The CSS solution does that.